# Convert.ToDateTime in Java

Tags: c#, java

Here's my code in c#.

```
DateTime gmtTime = Convert.ToDateTime(string.Format("{0} {1}", day[1], day[2])).Add(Convert.ToDateTime(time).TimeOfDay);
```

What I've tried in Java.

```
String month = "Jul";
        String day = "22";
        String gmtTime = String.format("%s %s", month, day);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
        Date gmtDate = df.parse (gmtTime);
```

The result I'm getting into Java is July 22, 1970. How can I get the current year just like in C# when I convert a String to DateTime the year is the current year. Is possible to have a code just like what I've tried in my c# code to transfer it to Java?

Hoping to get a good result. Thanks

Comment: I realised after why it was tagged..

Comment: You are not setting the year... Just add it to the above code.

Comment: Is it possible to set automatically the current year just like in c# when converting a String to datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
 int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 System.out.println(year);
```

Will give the current year

Comment: Thanks bro this what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines:

```
String gmtTime = String.format("%s %s", month, day);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
```

To this:

```
String gmtTime = String.format("%s %s %s", month, day, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding year to your Java SimpledateFormat, see the formats used here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final Date currentTime = new Date();
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");

// Set time zone  
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("Current Time: " + sdf.format(currentTime));
```

Here simply formatting current date-

```
final DateFormat reportDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);        
Date date = new Date();
String dateString = reportDateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(dateString);
```